# How to group results on a specific order?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a VIEW that contains a lot of information from multiple tables. When executing a query in this VIEW I need to group the results through the values of a column.

My main problem is that when grouping the results are not coming in the order I need. I noticed that at the time of grouping my database ends up getting the first distinct record it finds in the column indicated for and ignores the rest.

The thing is, I need the last line containing the grouping word. I have already tried to sort before doing the grouping but even so my database engine seems to ignore the ordering done before.

Using the table below as an example of my view, here's my question:

How could I know which was the last date on which each color was registered by a character?

That is, I need all the table columns ORDER by DATE DESC and GROUP by COLOR.

```
+------+------------+-------+------------+
| id   | name       | color | date       |
+------+------------+-------+------------+
|    1 | SweetRobin | Green | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Tyrion     | Red   | 2017-02-01 |
|    3 | Sansa      | Grey  | 2017-03-01 |
|    4 | Ned        | Grey  | 2017-04-01 |
|    5 | Margaery   | Green | 2017-05-01 |
|    6 | Oberyn     | Red   | 2017-06-01 |
+------+------------+-------+------------+
```

By my experience if I use

```
SELECT * FROM caracter GROUP BY color the output will be:
```

```
+------+------------+-------+------------+
| id   | name       | color | date       |
+------+------------+-------+------------+
|    1 | SweetRobin | Green | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Tyrion     | Red   | 2017-02-01 |
|    3 | Sansa      | Grey  | 2017-03-01 |
+------+------------+-------+------------+
```

But what I really need is this:

```
+------+----------+-------+------------+
| id   | name     | color | date       |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
|    4 | Ned      | Grey  | 2017-04-01 |
|    5 | Margaery | Green | 2017-05-01 |
|    6 | Oberyn   | Red   | 2017-06-01 |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Show the SQL and PHP code used to generate the output, not just the output. Edit your question to add the code.

Comment: There is o PHP code. Just the need to  know which was the last date on which each color was registered by a character?

By my experience if I use SELECT * FROM caracter GROUP BY color the output will be:

1 SweetRobin Green 2017-01-01
2 Tyrion         Red         2017-02-01
3 Sansa         Grey 2017-03-01

But what I need is

4 Ned                 Grey 2017-04-01
5 Margaery         Green 2017-05-01
6 Oberyn         Red         2017-06-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do you can try

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM (
  SELECT color, MAX(date) date
    FROM caracter
   GROUP BY color
) q JOIN caracter c 
    ON q.color = c.color 
   AND q.date = c.date
 ORDER BY id
```

The idea is that you first grab the max date per color and then join back to get all other columns.

Output:

```
+------+----------+-------+------------+
| id   | name     | color | date       |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
|    4 | Ned      | Grey  | 2017-04-01 |
|    5 | Margaery | Green | 2017-05-01 |
|    6 | Oberyn   | Red   | 2017-06-01 |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=10376d89943f0c4cf1e4d25e59db8aa6) demo

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Three days on the search of this answer.

Thank you very much. Not only for the answer but for the edit on the post too.

Can you tel me how to make this tables on the post?

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. You can use `<pre>` tags to insert plain ascii table output that you get from mysql console. You can also click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44739211/edit) your post and see how it's done.